# Put the text content of a website into a variable vba Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, http, uuid, guid

This function is wrong:

```
Function UUID() As String
    UUID = Workbooks.OpenText("https://www.uuidgenerator.net/api/version1") 'Compile Error: Expected Function Or Variable
End Function
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: What's the exact error message reported, and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Compile Error: Expected Function Or Variable

Comment: That's telling you that `Workbooks.OpenText()` isn't a function or a variable. Presumably, it's supposed to be a function; where it it defined? This type of question is probably better asked in [so], but you will need to provide a lot more information, and a minimum, complete, verifiable example, or it will be closed.

Comment: when I click "Ask" on stackoverflow i get a message that says: "You have reached your question limit"

Comment: not exists example for this unfortunately, simply i want put text content of an url in an variable.

Comment: Where did you come up with this code from? Is this your entire code? If so, where does `Workbooks.OpenText()` come from? You need to provide a whole lot more information before you can get any useful assistance - regardless of whether it's here, or on StackOverflow.

Comment: this is my full code. The function is called by an cell.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with `OpenText()`? Open the URL in a browser?  Do you have a function called `OpenText`? You need to post that. If this is the *only* code, then you're getting an error because `OpenText()` does not exist.

Comment: I'm trying to put the content of a website into a variable

Comment: As far as not being allowed to ask on StackOverflow, because of having reached your question limit, you should see the [complete rate-limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

Comment: I ask a few questions in a long time. I have made a total of 11 questions in almost 1 year.

Comment: This seems extremely broad. What are you trying to get, exactly. "Content of a website" can be the images in there, the HTML, certain elements, etc...FYI [`OpenText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) is for files, not websites.

Comment: I'm trying to put the text content of a website into a variable

Comment: I have changed the title of the question, I hope that the informations is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to add a reference to you project in VBA, to give you access to MSXML:

1. Microsoft XML, v 3.0.
2. Microsoft XML, v 4.0 (if you have installed MSXML 4.0 separately).
3. Microsoft XML, v 5.0 (if you have installed Office 2003 – 2007 which provides MSXML 5.0 for Microsoft Office Applications).
4. Microsoft XML, v 6.0 for latest versions of MS Office.

   ```
   Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String

   myurl = "http://requestb.in/15oxrjh1" //replace with your URL

   xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False

   xmlhttp.Send

   MsgBox(xmlhttp.responseText)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ttaylor1218:

```
Function UUID(Version As Integer) As String
    Dim HTTP As Object
    Set HTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    HTTP.Open "GET", "https://www.uuidgenerator.net/api/version" & Version, False
    HTTP.Send
    UUID = Replace(HTTP.ResponseText, vbCrLf, "")
End Function
```